# How to add proper column's title

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs development. I have the following piece of code

```
 <table id="searchTable" ng-show="results" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-list">
                        <thead search-table-header table="table" search="search()">

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @*<tr>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                            </tr>*@
                            <tr ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="loadView(result)">

                                <td class="col-md-10">
                                    {{ result.descrip }}
                                    <span class="label label-danger pull-right" ng-show="result.hidden">Hidden</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">
                                    {{ result.tmplType | passTicket}}
                                    <span class="label label-danger pull-right" ng-show="result.hidden">Hidden</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

As a result of this code the headers for the columns show Descrip and tmplType. You see I tried to introduce headers using th, but this didn't help and my headers show up right below the wrong column headers. I am not sure how can I change this code (or where should I change code) to show proper column titles?

I examined the searchTableHeader directive and it has the following html:

```
<tr style='-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;'>
    <th ng-repeat="column in table.columns" ng-click="sort(column)">
        {{ column.name }}
        <span class="pull-right" href="#" ng-show="column.name === table.sort">
            <i ng-class="{'icon-chevron-down': table.dir === 'asc', 'icon-chevron-up': table.dir === 'desc'}"></i>
        </span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

So, I suspect I need to somehow make this more flexible. This doesn't seem simple to me - anyone has ideas?

UPDATE. I made a bit of a progress and now my task is the following: 
In the controller for one particular view I made a change from original code to this one:

```
  $scope.table = searchScreenService.getTable('Descrip', [
                { name: 'Descrip', displayName: 'Description' }, { name: 'TmplType', displayName: 'Type' }
            ]);
```

So, I just added new property displayName.

Now, in that search header template which is used across the whole project I need to add the following modification: currently we use {{column.name}}

I need to use displayName if that property exists and name if that property does not exist. So, do you know how to fix that small piece of code?

Comment: Can you provide some Fiddle/PLunker?

Comment: The `tr` containing the `th`s should be inside the `thead` element.

Comment: I tried that also but it still shows wrong :( I am not sure about how to provide Fiddle. I am using Google Chrome for testing, I'll try to open Developers console now and check closer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ and skip the razor stuffs it's confusing has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: What do you mean by skip razor stuffs? I took the code from the VS 2012. We're using MVC + Angular. This is what I see in Developer's Console in Google Chrome http://www.universalthread.com/Thread%20photos/2014/01602012.png

Comment: Looking closer I found the following template for the header's directive (see updated post). So, it has to be adjusted here, I guess, but I don't know how

Comment: I made a bit more progress and now I am to the following challenge. I currently have the following code {{ column.name }} to display the column's title. I added a new property column.displayName but only in one controller. So, I want to somehow check, if I have that displayName defined and if yes, use it, otherwise use column.name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution in another forum. In the searchTableHeader template I added this code

```
<span ng-if="column.displayName == undefined || column.displayName == ''">{{column.name}}</span>
<span ng-if="column.displayName != undefined && column.displayName != ''">{{column.displayName}}</span>
```

and now I can add dynamically displayName property (should probably name it differently, though) and the caption will be displayed correctly. If the property is not defined, it is using the column.name.